# How do I display all available field types?

Tags: forms, console

I want generate an new form in a custom module via the `generate:form` command.

In this step, I must enter a field type.

[image]

How can I get all available field types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the term "field type" you probably don't find what you are looking for. Better search for "form and render elements". You can find a list of all available elements here:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements/8.2.x

You can use all elements of the type "FormElement".

Comment: Thank you :) I'm surprised , I don't see any taxonomy field type

Comment: That's a real field type (which are used to store data), in D8 that is not a separate field type, but an entity reference field.

Comment: If you want to store data, generate a custom entity with field types and then use an entity form.